# Möller–Trumbore distance differs from Point-Plane distance when ray goes along normal

Tags: math, raycasting

Given this:

```
Vector3 p_a = (-8720, 1105, -5249)
Vector3 p_b = (-13149, 1124, -5249)
Vector3 p_c = (-13330, 1103, -3404) //p_a p_b, p_c are the points of the triangle
Vector3 p_q = (-11737, 1071, -4678)
Vector3 normal = new Vector3(0.0000000, 0.9999285, 0.0119620) //(0, 4096, 49) normalized
```

If I calculate the distance from the point **p_q** to the plane created by the triangle using 
`Vector3.Dot((p_q - p_a), normal)` The result is 27.16

However if I throw a ray from **p_q** along the normal and find the distance using Möller–Trumbore algorithm ([this implementation](http://wiki.peaktutors.com/index.php/M%C3%B6ller%E2%80%93Trumbore_intersection_algorithm) to precise, altough I tried with different ones and got the same result) I get that the distance to the intersection is 40.2

Since the ray using Möller–Trumbore goes along the normal, if I get an intersection shouldn't I get the same distance? I must be missing something obvious but I cannot see what.

Comment: Well, the problem is that your "normal" isn't the normal of the triangle. To calculate the normal, take the cross product of `b-a` with `c-a` and normalize the result.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The normal should be the normal of the triangle, there might be some precision missing since the normal suffers precision lost due to some conversion to fixed point math. So the precision seems to be the culprit here, otherwise the results should be exactly the same right?

Comment: well, the precession isn't the problem. The normal is just wrong. It can't have its x=0.